# Python found No module named package that is installed with conda install

Tags: python, package, conda, importerror

I do notice there are some similar question asked by different people about why python couldn't locate the packages that are installed using `conda install` command in their conda environment.

Take pyqt for example.

1 I create conda environment:
`conda create -n myenv python=2.7 pip`

2 Activate environment:
`source activate myenv`

3 install packages:
`conda install pyqt`

4 run python:
`python`
`import pyqt`

Error report:
ImportError: No module named pyqt

5 check out packages installed:
`pip list` doesn't give pyqt
but `conda list` will show pyqt installed

6 I just noticed that the `"conda install" packges are under /env/conda-meta`, but `"pip install" packges are under env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (and bunch paths sys.path gives)`.

If we could simply append the /env/conda-meta to the path, it'll be great, but after appending operation, I eixt() python and re-run python, checking out the sys.path again, the /env/conda-meta is not there anymore.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: related question found here with better case description (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461944/cannot-import-packages-installed-in-new-conda-environment#comment93283513_51461944). But I want to know how to append to sys.path in this situation.

Comment: Please visit at least one tutorial to see which imports are actually valid https://build-system.fman.io/pyqt5-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're using the wrong module name.  The correct import statement for `pyqt` is

```
import PyQt5
```

or whatever version you installed.