# Can't import package after installing in a conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, gdal

I tried to install `gdal` package on my conda environment. I activated gcpy environment and installed the gdal package using `conda install -c conda-forge gdal`. The package installs successfully. But, when I tried to import the package, I get error:

```
In [1]: import gdal
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ee38efafc30b> in <module>
----> 1 import gdal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdal'
```

I can see the package in the `conda list`.

```
gdal                      3.2.1            py39h409cc32_1    conda-forge
geos                      3.8.1                he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
geoschem-gcpy             1.0.0            py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.6.0                h5d11630_3    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          h0b5b191_1005    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                h36c2ea0_2    conda-forge
glib                      2.66.4               hc4f0c31_2    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.66.4               hc4f0c31_2    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.14.5               h0935bb2_2    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.18.3               h3560a44_0    conda-forge
h5netcdf                  0.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
h5py                      3.1.0           nompi_py39h25020de_100    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13            h10796ff_1004    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_h6a2412b_1114    conda-forge
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
helpdev                   0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
icu                       68.1                 h58526e2_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
imagesize                 1.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        3.4.0            py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        3.4.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
intervaltree              3.0.2                      py_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 5.4.2            py39hef51801_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.19.0           py39hef51801_2    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
isort                     5.7.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.17.2           py39hf3d152e_1    conda-forge
jeepney                   0.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.2             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
json-c                    0.13.1            hbfbb72e_1002    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0                      py_2    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.11             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.7.0            py39hf3d152e_1    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.14               h0042707_0    conda-forge
keyring                   22.0.1           py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.3.1            py39h1a9c180_1    conda-forge
krb5                      1.17.2               h926e7f8_0    conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.3            py39h07f9747_2    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.11                 hcbb858e_1    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.35.1               hea4e1c9_1    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                7_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                7_openblas    conda-forge
libclang                  11.0.1          default_ha53f305_1    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.71.1               hcdd3856_8    conda-forge
libdap4                   3.20.6               h1d1bd15_1    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               hcdb4288_3    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h58526e2_2    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h2828fa1_18    conda-forge
libgdal                   3.2.1                h52563cd_1    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            9.3.0               hff62375_18    conda-forge
libgfortran5              9.3.0               hff62375_18    conda-forge
libglib                   2.66.4               h748fe8e_2    conda-forge
libgomp                   9.3.0               h2828fa1_18    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h516909a_0    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             h74f7ee3_1012    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                7_openblas    conda-forge
libllvm11                 11.0.1               hf817b99_0    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.7.4           nompi_h56d31a8_107    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.41.0               h8cfc5f6_2    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.12          pthreads_h4812303_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h21135ba_2    conda-forge
libpq                     12.3                 h255efa7_3    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libspatialindex           1.9.3                he1b5a44_3    conda-forge
libspatialite             5.0.0                heaf302f_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.9.0                hab1572f_5    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.3.0               h6de172a_18    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.2.0                hdc55705_0    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h7f98852_1000    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.1.0                h36c2ea0_3    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
libxkbcommon              1.0.3                he3ba5ed_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.10               h72842e0_3    conda-forge
```

I tried `conda update --all` as said [Here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8716) . I also tried all similar question. But, still no solution.

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461944/cannot-import-packages-installed-in-new-conda-environment)
[Reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767012/conda-list-shows-a-package-but-cannot-import-it)

Answer (score 1):

There are five major modules that are included with the GDAL Python bindings.:

```
 from osgeo import gdal
 from osgeo import ogr
 from osgeo import osr
 from osgeo import gdal_array
 from osgeo import gdalconst
```

Additionally, there are five compatibility modules that are included but provide notices to state that they are deprecated and will be going away. If you are using GDAL 1.7 bindings, you should update your imports to utilize the usage above, but the following will work until at least GDAL 2.1.

```
 import gdal
 import ogr
 import osr
 import gdalnumeric
 import gdalconst
```

If you have previous code that imported the global module and still need to support the old import, a simple try…except import can silence the deprecation warning and keep things named essentially the same as before:

```
    try:
        from osgeo import gdal
    except ImportError:
        import gdal
```